# Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I am getting this error message when i tried to host my mvc website on local IIS server on my PC . and tried to access it from my web browser.

Please help me how to get rid of this problem. I want to host my mvc3 website on my local IIS server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the user account that is running the application has read and write access to %temp% folder